# TableView Controller -Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cells

I'm trying to present an array of names into cells of tableview controller.

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController 
{

    var names = ["aA", "aB", "cC"]

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
    {
        return names.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = names[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

When I simulate it, nothing has appeared into the cells!
[image: As in the image here]

What's wrong with my Code! 
The compiler did not give me any errors.

Comment: numberOfSectionsInTableView ... return 1 or completely remove that method

Comment: After change the numberOfSections, check if you link the view in the storyboard to your class.

Comment: @EICaptain checking datasource/delegate *should* be unnecessary here as we're dealing with a `UITableViewController` subclass.

Comment: @nhgrif ohh.. right i didn't notice that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update number of sections. Your problem will be solved.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Comment: Or just delete the method entirely.

Comment: Have you set delegate and datasource to the your current view controller?